# Raspberry pi sudo apt-get install apache2 gives error (404 Not Found)

Tags: linux, ssh, raspberry-pi, apache2, raspberry-pi2

I have been following this tutorial and I now cannot finish it by running:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T3s9KYCU3tE

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

What I am trying to do is basically turn my raspberry pi into a wifi pineapple! This tutorial has gone well so far but when I run this it gives me this error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
apache2-bin apache2-data apache2-utils libapr1 libaprutil1 libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3 libaprutil1-ldap liblua5.1-0 ssl-cert
Suggested packages:
apache2-doc apache2-suexec-pristine apache2-suexec-custom openssl-blacklist
The following NEW packages will be installed:
apache2 apache2-bin apache2-data apache2-utils libapr1 libaprutil1libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3 libaprutil1-ldap liblua5.1-0 ssl-cert
0 upgraded, 10 newly installed, 0 to remove and 256 not upgraded.
Need to get 1,750 kB of archives.
After this operation, 5,241 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
libapr1 libaprutil1 libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3 libaprutil1-ldap liblua5.1-0 apache2-bin apache2-utils apache2-data apache2 ssl-cert
Install these packages without verification? [y/N] y
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie/main libapr1 armhf 1.5.1-3
404  Not Found
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie/main libaprutil1 armhf 1.5.4-1
404  Not Found
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie/main libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3 armhf 1.5.4-1
404  Not Found
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie/main libaprutil1-ldap armhf 1.5.4-1
404  Not Found
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie/main liblua5.1-0 armhf 5.1.5-7.1
404  Not Found
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie/main apache2-bin armhf 2.4.10-10+deb8u7
404  Not Found
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie/main apache2-utils armhf 2.4.10-10+deb8u7
404  Not Found
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie/main apache2-data all 2.4.10-10+deb8u7
404  Not Found
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie/main apache2 armhf 2.4.10-10+deb8u7
404  Not Found
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie/main ssl-cert all 1.0.35
404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/a/apr/libapr1_1.5.1-3_armhf.deb  404  Not Found

E: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/a/apr-util/libaprutil1_1.5.4-1_armhf.deb  404  Not Found

E: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/a/apr-util/libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3_1.5.4-1_armhf.deb  404  Not Found

E: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/a/apr-util/libaprutil1-ldap_1.5.4-1_armhf.deb  404  Not Found

E: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/l/lua5.1/liblua5.1-0_5.1.5-7.1_armhf.deb  404  Not Found

E: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/a/apache2/apache2-bin_2.4.10-10+deb8u7_armhf.deb  404  Not Found

E: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/a/apache2/apache2-utils_2.4.10-10+deb8u7_armhf.deb  404  Not Found

E: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/a/apache2/apache2-data_2.4.10-10+deb8u7_all.deb  404  Not Found

E: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/a/apache2/apache2_2.4.10-10+deb8u7_armhf.deb  404  Not Found

E: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/s/ssl-cert/ssl-cert_1.0.35_all.deb  404  Not Found

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on the S.E. related sites http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/ or http://superuser.com. Use the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. Please read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: ok thank you shellter!

Comment: this is because your raspberry is not updated, still pointing to old repos. For fix it you should update it, you can follow the instructions here. After that all work as expected for me and not more 404. https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/os.html

Answer (score 2):

Need to update package lists

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

When that's done:

```
sudo reboot
```

Now retry the apache2 install.

Thanks,
Hope this helps.

Comment: it actually gives a similar error when i run this! What should i do?

Comment: try a dist upgrade:

" sudo apt-get dist-upgrade "

and see if that works. If not, there may be a problem with apt

Comment: that gives a similar error too!! UHG :( this is the error

Comment: heres some of the Error:mods/raspberrypi-net-mods_1.2.5_all.deb  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/pool/ui/r/raspberrypi-ui-mods/raspberrypi-ui-mods_1.20161206_all.deb  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/r/ruby2.1/ruby2.1_2.1.5-2+deb8u3_armhf.deb  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/pool/main/s/sonic-pi/sonic-pi_2.11.0-0_armhf.deb  404  Not Found
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?

Comment: still the same! :( uhg

Comment: please help Harvey.

Comment: Good morning!
Please could you post the contents of your /etc/apt/sources.list
This file is where apt looks to find the packages. It can be viewed by: sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list

Comment: ok Thank you, i will try that, your help is much appreciated i'll come back with the results!

Comment: this is what i found deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie main contrib non-free r$
# Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
#deb-src http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie main contrib non-free rpi

Comment: Your sources list appears to be okay. Have you tried to re flash the image to the SD card and reinstall the raspberry pi OS?

Comment: would that delete all my progress on the tutorial, not that it's a big deal, it's pretty easy to redo.

Comment: is there no other solution?? Would everything i do in the process (the tutorial, make this happen again.)??

Comment: Is your raspberry pi connected to the internet? An E:: error usually means that it couldn't reach the package source. Please try "ping 8.8.8.8" in the command line and tell me if you get a "Reply from" message. Thanks.

Comment: OK i will do that, i'm pretty sure it's connected but i'll check again i'm sshing into it so how can i connect through cmd/terminal?

Comment: If it's connected, I can't think of any other cause.

Comment: OK if it is i'll try re flashing the operating system onto the card.

Comment: I'm all out of ideas here. Looks like re flashing your OS is the only solution. Sorry I couldn't be of more help.

Comment: Ok thank you very much for the help, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. Go to testipv6.com and see if all ipv6 sites appear down to you. Basically meaning, you have no ipv6 connectivity. That's where I have left this... I think it's my ISP, and it may be yours as well.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).